# sscanf equivalent for std::string

Tags: c++

I have a string of the form std::string str = "1001 0104 2325 9999" and I need to store these four substrings seperated by spaces in integers . Is there an elegant way to do this task like there is with strings in C(using sscanf) ? This is not a homework question .

Comment: Look up [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Comment: @BaummitAugen `std::istringstream` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way would probably be to use a stringstream with an istream_iterator, something like this:

```
std::string str = "1001 0104 2325 9999";

std::istringstream in(str);

std::vector<int> numbers {
    std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
    std::istream_iterator<int>()
};

// just to show what we did:
for (int i : numbers)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

Note that there is a little bit of ambiguity in the input you provided: it's not clear whether you intent the `0104` to be decimal or octal (as a leading zero would cause it to be interpreted in source code). The code I've written above interprets it as decimal. If you want a leading `0` to mean octal (and leading `0x` to mean hexadecimal) you can do that (at least if memory serves) by setting the base for the conversion to 0.

Comment: To treat a leading `0` as octal, you set the `basefield` to `0`.  `in.setf( std::ios_base::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::basefield )`, because there is no specified flag or manipulator for this.  As to whether this is the best solution: it depends on whether he has a variable number of fields ore not.  If it should be exactly four integers each time, `in >> i1 >> i2 >> i3 >> i4` is better, with error checking to ensure that there aren't any more fields.